Toilet Flange is higher than the subfloor and slightly angled - Keep. or replace?
I'm about to install new vinyl flooring but noticed that the toilet flange is rusted a bit, slightly angled, and higher than the subfloor and the new floor.
https://imgur.com/RjfDeRs

Should I cut out and replace just the metal ring? before I install the toilet? I might still end up with a gap though.

Instead of having the vinyl plank underneath the ring, I tried attaching a luan plyboard ring that I could place underneath/ like a wooden shim to keep it stable and then I could screw it in with some wood/deck screws?  I'm doing this so that the vinyl plank is not affected... I will seal the gap between the vinyl and the plywood+ ring with siliconized caulk. Would that work?  https://imgur.com/MH1gdRA

I've had no issues with the toilet rocking or anything like that.. so wondering if I should just let it be. Install a new Wax ring / Danco rubber+ wax ring and call it a day?



Hi. If RMDman's answer works for you, you should click on the check mark by his answer to accept the answer.

Hey @JohnPolo The first part worked but not sure about the Sani seal. First of all its not available and then I've found mixed reviews for that product so a bit hesitant to wait for it to be delivered. I was hoping to get more responses on the options available here - wax ring / Better than wax - fluid master seal. Is there a better way to do this?

I don't know much about plumbing in general or toilets specifically. There are several posts on this site. I recently had issues with replacing a toilet and there is lots of information on my post: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/298034/toilet-rocks-regardless-how-tight-floor-bolts-are-turned/298368#298368  and I see in the related questions for your question this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57432/does-the-toilet-flange-need-to-be-bolted?  Maybe you can find more information that can help you? I tried several different rings/seals and none worked well for my case.

If it were me, I'd do as you planned, however I would use this soft rubber seal.
I have used them on dozens of toilets and never had an issue. It makes having a flange that is high or low, or not level a non-issue.  They are a little pricey, but well worth it. Some of the bigbox stores carry them too.  Far better performing than other foam/ rubber rings. If you need to remove the toilet for any reason, the seal can be reused.

Do you mean go ahead with the plywood shim to level the existing flange and screw it into the subfloor right? Also, I checked, and this rubber seal you mentioned is available near me... I have standard or jumbo wax rings/Danco rubber+ wax / Fluidmaster better than wax/korky wax ring. these are the available

#1 yes use the plywood shim and screw the flange down, but not too tight to deform the ring.    #2 NONE of the seals you mentioned work as well or have the soft forming properties of the SaniSeal.  I don't recommend or use any of the ones you mentioned.

Got it, thanks! The sani seal would have to be shipped out and it'd take a week, cant wait that long.. so I'd probably have to go with the standard wax ring I guess

It is normal/proper to have the flange/ring 1/4" proud of the final finished floor. It is not normal/proper to have the flange unsecured and supported only by the pipe.
